# Kolmogorov-Smirnov test in R

Tags: r, statistics, statistical-test, kolmogorov-smirnov

I tried to use the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to test normality of a sample. This is a small simple example of what I do:

```
x <- rnorm(1e5, 1, 2)
ks.test(x, "pnorm")
```

Here is the result R gives me:

```
        One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x
D = 0.3427, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

The p-value is very low whereas the test should accept the null-hypothesis.

I do not understand why it does not work.

Comment: you're testing against a standard normal above; try `ks.test(x,"pnorm",1,2)`

Comment: You may also find this interesting: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As pointed out in the `ks.test` [help](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/ks.test.html), you have to give to the `ks.test` function the arguments of `pnorm`. If you do not precise mean and standard variation, the test is done on a standard gaussian distribution.

Here you should write:

```
ks.test(x, "pnorm", 1, 2) #or ks.test(x, "pnorm", mean=1, sd=2)
```

Answer (score 14):

I think it would be better to use `mean=mean(x)` and `sd=sd(x)` like

```
ks.test(x, "pnorm", mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x))
```